# I need to certificates using keystore file having an extension ".store" provided from client supported by tibco BW project

Tags: tibco

Using the "server.store" file provided by the customer i need to create the certificate and the password for the keystore and also i need to know what format does the "server.store" has been provided. PKS or PEM format? how do i check the format from the existing "server.store" file.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your server.store is a keystore,
did you try with keytool?

You should be able to  list the certificates with:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore server.store
```

and export with

```
keytool -export -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore server.store
```

then you can export the certificate and convert it between format following one of the many tutorials on the web.
A couple of useful links:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106631

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

HTH.